# Get author_id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, get, author

I'm having problems to get author_id in this code. Don't show nothing. Some can help me?

Entire code: (I'm trying get custom_post_type value of the same author of post.

```
<?php global $query_string;

query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' ); ?>

<?php while(have_posts()): the_post();
$author = get_the_author();
echo 'Autor:'.$author;
$ofertas = array();

// Second Loop
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'author' => $author_id,
    'post_type' => 'ofertas'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); // check if it has offers, if it has, loop over the offers
        $ofertas[$i]['title'] = get_the_title(); // or anything you need
            $i++;
    endwhile; // close the
 else: // if it has no post
    continue; // we don't display the post
endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

Comment: Have you try <?php the_author_ID(); ?>

Comment: thanks @dksaini14 i know that, but how i put that inside the loop in this code?

Comment: [I would suggest please don't use `the_author_ID`  as its deprecated in latest version](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_ID)

Comment: Use `the_author_meta('ID')`

Comment: Yeah @chiragswadia with this show me the real post author but show all "ofertas" in every post. You know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users('role=author');
foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
    echo 'Author ID: '.$user->ID;
    $author_id = $user->ID;    
    $ofertas = array();

    // Second Loop
    $i = 0;
    $args = array(
        'author' => $author_id,
        'post_type' => 'ofertas'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); // check if it has offers, if it has, loop over the offers
            $ofertas[$i]['title'] = get_the_title(); // or anything you need
                $i++;
        endwhile; // close the
     else: // if it has no post
        continue; // we don't display the post
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
} // end foreach

?>
```

Does this suit your requirements ?

Comment: If i put that code, resultant html is: "Autor:zinc 1314Autor:prueba" and post dissapear. why?

Comment: @vektor We are only displaying author ids in this loop. We are not showing post title and content in the loop. Do you need to show posts title and content too ?

Comment: I have updated the code with get_the_author_meta()  function. Plz try this

Comment: but i need declare $author_id for get custom_post_types

Comment: @vektor I`ll update a detailed code in my above answer. Wait 5 mins

Comment: @vektor please check the updated code in my above answer. Is it what you need ?